# How do I display images in a footer?

Tags: laravel

I have stored logos in the database and want to display them in the footer which is included `@include('layouts.footer')`. I am fetching images from the database using this code

```
 public function show(){
        $logo = DB::table('logos')->get();
        return view('layouts.footer',['logo'=>$logo]);
 }
```

I want to display these images in the footer using

```
    <div class="footer">
       @foreach($logo as $l)
          {{ $l->company_name}}
          {{ $l->company_logo}}
       @endforeach
    <p class="footer-text">&copy; Copyright <?php echo date("Y"); ?> Hotel Store Partners</p>
</div>
```

but returns an error "undefined variable logo".
What is the correct way to display the images in the footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using *View Composer*
In you AppserviceProvider `boot` method you can gather these name and pass to all Views **at once**.
[Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QWZxjgvEQc&list=PLpzy7FIRqpGD5pN3-Y66YDtxJCYuGumFO&index=2)

Comment: Thanks. I followed this to get the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can achieve this:
1. Put this code in footer.

```
@php
   $logo = DB::table('logos')->get();
@endphp
<div class="footer">
  @if(count($logo))
   @foreach($logo as $l)
      {{ $l->company_name}}
      {{ $l->company_logo}}
   @endforeach
  @endif
   <p class="footer-text">&copy; Copyright <?php echo date("Y"); ?> Hotel Store Partners</p>
</div>
```

But this method is a bad practice

2. Create FooterComposer

   public function compose(View $view)
   {
   $logo = DB::table('logos')->get();
   $view->with(['logo'=>$logo]);
   }

Now $logo will be accessible in footer.

Answer (score 0):

I have used View Composer. 
In AppServiceProvider boot method, I added this code:

```
public function boot()
    {
        View::composer('layouts.app', function($view){
            $view->with('logo', Logo::all());
        });
    }
```

In the Controller, I used this code:

```
return view('layouts.footer');
```

In the footer, I  used this code:

```
        <footer>
            @foreach($logo as $l)
                <p>{{ $l->company_name }}</p>
                <img src="https://partners.hotelstore.co.ke/public{{ $l->company_logo }}" style="width:100px; height:75px;">

            @endforeach
            <p class="footer-text">&copy; Copyright <?php echo date("Y"); ?> Hotel Store Partners</p>
        </footer>
```

This is what finally displayed the images on the footer.